# $[T,S]:=TS-ST=I$ cannot holds

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on an infinite dimensional complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

> Let $T,S\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. I want to prove that the equality
>   \begin{equation}\label{commz}
> [T,S]:=TS-ST=I \tag{1},
> \end{equation}
>    cannot hold.

To see this, assume that $(1)$ holds. We shall prove by induction that
 \begin{equation}\label{tag2}
[T, S^n] = nS^{n - 1},\;n\in \mathbb{N}^*.
\end{equation}
 By assumption, $[T,S]=S^{0}=I$. Suppose $[T,S^{n}]= nS^{n-1}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. Then
\begin{align*}
   [T,S^{n+1}]
  & = TS^{n+1}-S^{n+1}T\\
    & =(TS^{n}-S^{n}T)S+S^{n}TS-S^{n+1}T \\
     & = [T,S^{n}]S+S^{n}[T,S] \\
     & = nS^{n-1}S+S^{n}=(n+1) S^{n}.
\end{align*}
So,
\begin{equation*}\label{tag11}
TS^n - S^nT = n S^{n=1},
\end{equation*}
holds for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. Hence,
\begin{align*}
n\|S^{n-1}\|
& = \|TS^n - S^nT\|\\
 &\leq 2 \|T\|\cdot\|S^{n} \|\\
 &\leq 2 \|T\|\cdot\|S\|\cdot\|S^{n-1} \|.
\end{align*}

If $\|S^{n-1} \|\ne 0$, we get $n \le 2 \|T\|\|S\|$, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$. This leads to a contradiction. So, $(1)$ cannot hold for $T,S\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

> Why $S^{n-1}\ne 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$?

Comment: If $S^n=0$ for some $n$, take $n$ to be the smallest such; what can you say about $nS^{n-1}$, and so about $S^{n-1}$  ?

Comment: Why not just take $S=I$? Then it's always 0.  Not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: @MattSamuel I assume that $(1)$ holds for some $T,S$ not every.

Comment: I was so confused reading this because "$[T,S] = I$ cannot hold for every $T, S$" is logically equivalent to "there exists some $T, S$ such that $[T,S] \ne I$" What should be said instead is "for every $T, S, [T, S] \ne I$" @Matt Samuel

Comment: @TrevorGunn Thank you for the remark. Please see my edit.

Comment: @MaximeRamzi Can you please tell me why infinite dimensional Hilbert space? I can not see where we invoked infiniteness and Hilbert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the conclusion holds only if $S^{n-1}\ne 0$.
But, assume $S^k=0$ for some $k$, then by your formula $[T, S^k] =kS^{k-1}$, we get $S^{k-1}=0$, which in turn implies $S^{k-2}=0$, and so on, until $S=0$ which is impossible, provided that $[T, S] =I$.

Comment: You have show that $S^k$ is non zero for all positive integer k?

Comment: Yes, based on your identity.

Comment: According to my question, We can prove also that the equality
$$[T, S] = \lambda I, \; 0 \ne \lambda \in \mathbb{C},$$
cannot hold, since the above equality may be written as $[T,\lambda^{-1}S]=I$ and this is impossible. Do you  agree with me? Thanks.