# Operator $A$ such that $AA^{*}-A^{*}A=I$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Is there a Hilbert space $H$ and a (bounded) operator $A:H\to H$ such that $AA^{*}-A^{*}A=I$? In finite dimensions the answer is no because of trace. But I can't seem to condradict this in general. It is equivalent to $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle A^{*}x,A^{*}y\rangle-\langle Ax,Ay\rangle$, but I coudn't really continue from here.

Any hint are idea will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: For a curious example of the unbounded case of extreme importance to quantum physics, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Hamiltonian_and_energy_eigenstates

Comment: you might be interested in this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3080944/t-s-ts-st-i-cannot-holds